# NAS Streaming Performance

Tags: macos, nas

I recently bought a NAS drive (WD Personal Cloud) and it seems great - for everything but streaming video, it is very quick. However, when playing video files (480 and 720p) despite there being no other network traffic, VLC still occasionally pauses for about two seconds, then continues to play.

This happens about every ten minutes, and I was wondering if there is a) a better app, b) a way to tell VLC to cache ahead of time or c) something I'm doing wrong.

I'm on a Wireless N network, zero other traffic - I was thinking it might potentially be the mac doing other internet related stuff in the background, but that's just an idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have since found a solution for this and would like to share:

VLC (and most other video apps) have a network caching feature. By default its set at 1/100th of a second or so - using the images below you can increase it.

The trade-off is that you have to wait a few seconds when skipping or loading a film.

1 - http://img.iamp.me/i5bN (click show all, bottom left)

2 - http://img.iamp.me/65qz

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the video playback on the local computer first to avoid the problem is related to your video itself.